# call to undefined function in PHP

Tags: php, function, while-loop

I have a PHP code which I am using to display the list of comments from my database to the webpage.

CODE-

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) { // Loop through results of query

  if ($row['depth'] > $cur_depth) {
   if($row['depth'] == 1){
   echo "<ul>\n";
    runthis();
    $cur_depth = $row['depth'];
   }
    else   if($row['depth'] == 2){
      echo "<ul class='selected'>\n";
      runthat();
      $cur_depth = $row['depth'];
    }
    else{
    echo "<ul>\n";
    runthats();
    $cur_depth = $row['depth'];
    }
  }
  else while ($cur_depth > $row['depth']) {
    echo "</ul>\n";
    $cur_depth--;
  }
  function runthis(){
  echo "<li id=" .$row['depth'] . " class='some_class'>" . $row['comment'] . " &nbsp;id-". $row['category_id'] ."<a href='' id='toggle-cm'>reply</a><br/><div id='commentarea'><textarea row=5 cols=40>write something here...</textarea><br/><button id=" . $row['category_id'] . ">reply to this comment</button></div></li>\n";
  }

  function runthat(){
  echo "<li id=" .$row['depth'] . ">" . $row['comment'] . " &nbsp;id-". $row['category_id'] ."<a href='' id='toggle-cm'>reply</a><br/><div id='commentarea'><textarea row=5 cols=40>write something here...</textarea><br/><button id=" . $row['category_id'] . ">reply to this comment</button></div></li>\n";
  }
}
while ($cur_depth > -1) {
  echo "</ul>\n";
  $cur_depth--;
}
```

What it does is fetch the comments from the sql database and displays it in hierarchical manner. `$row['depth']` is variable that stores the depth of the comment. Now, I want to add class `some_class` to the `<li>` elements the has `row['depth']` = 1 and also assign some property to `<ul>` element that has `row['depth']` = 2.

Original code was working fine but I modified it a bit to assign classes and properties.

ORIGINAL CODE-

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) { // Loop through results of query
  if ($row['depth'] > $cur_depth) {
    echo "<ul>\n";
    $cur_depth = $row['depth'];
  }
  else while ($cur_depth > $row['depth']) {
    echo "</ul>\n";
    $cur_depth--;
  }
  echo "<li>" . $row['comment'] . "id-". $row['category_id'] ."<a href='' id='toggle-cm'>reply</a><br/><div id='commentarea'><textarea row=5 cols=40>write something here...</textarea><br/><button id=" . $row['category_id'] . ">reply to this comment</button></div></li>\n";
}
while ($cur_depth > -1) {
  echo "</ul>\n";
  $cur_depth--;
}
```

Now, what I want to achieve is to make some changes in this original code, so that some different property is assigned to `<li>` element that has `row['depth'] = 1` and some different property is applied to the `<ul>` element that has depth 2. I am getting error using the modified code I shown.

ERROR-

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function runthat()
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Well, what is it? `runthat` or `runthats`? Also... really?! No better function names you could come up with?

Comment: Don't declare function into a while !

Comment: even while declaring the function outside the while loop, it runs only once and do not run for entire while loop. Why is it so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace:

```
runthats();
```

by

```
runthat();
```

and do not use the function in a while

Comment: couldn't you see I have edited my answer???

Comment: do not use the function in a while... this is why it does not work

Comment: even while declaring the function outside the while loop, it runs only once and do not run for entire while loop. Why is it so?

Comment: you should make your code otherwise. For this kind of manipulation, you should use objects.